# If and Ideal of a Ring has a prime Ideal, then prime ideal is Ideal of the given Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

The problem statement is as follows:
Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $S$ be an ideal of $R$ and $T$ be a Prime Ideal of $S$. Prove that $T$ is an ideal of Ring $R$.

What I have tried:

We know that $T$ is a prime ideal of $S$.
So we can assert 1.) $T$ is itself a ring, and 2.) $T$ is a subset of $S$; hence $T$ is a subset of $R$

Now all we need to show is that for any elements  $r \in R$, and $t\in T$, their product $$rt\in T$$

What I have done for that  is:

For any element $s\in S$, $$rs\in S$$

Since $T$ is an ideal of $S$, for any $t\in T$, $$(rs)t\in T$$
Or,  $$r(st)\in T$$
But $$st \in T$$ hence $st=m$ for some $m\in T$.

Therefore, $$rm\in T$$
Hence $T$ is an ideal of $R$.
Now I know this proof is incorrect, because it does not make use of the fact that $T$ is a Prime Ideal.
Could you point mistake in my proof, and also give the correct proof?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does $R$ have a unit $1$?

Comment: The problem statement does not assume that. So I guess it is true for rings without unity as well. @HennoBrandsma

Comment: It’s just that if rings must have a unit, $S$, being an ideal, wouldn’t be a ring in the same sense as $R$.